# Windows Beep doesn't produce a sound in Windows 7 Credential Provider

Tags: windows, windows-7, beep

I am encountering a weird situation with the Windows Beep function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I understand that the Beep function uses the Windows Sound Drivers in Windows 7 instead of the Intel timer chip (used in Windows XP) to produce the sound.

I have a custom Credential Provider that executes some code that uses the Beep to indicate an event in the system. The same piece of code produces a sound in the Windows 7 desktop and the Windows 7 Lock CP (the CP that appears when you lock the desktop). However, in the Logon CP (the CP that appears on boot-up), there is no sound.

Does anyone know why this happens? I have googled a fair bit and people who have encountered such an issue run an application using "runas" with user credentials to produce the Beep. I would rather not use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Services cannot produce sounds in Windows 7. Afaik, there is no reasonable way around this...

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks. Yea, I discovered that and moved the Beep call to the client application (custom CP and a desktop application). The desktop component runs fine, but the custom CP refuses to generate any sounds when in CPUS_LOGON mode. However, it works fine when in CPUS_LOCK mode.